# Are there meaningful anagrams in Lord of the Rings character names?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, names

**Motivation**
I just observed that "Denethor", the human steward who thought himself king has all the same letters as the word "dethrone" which is what he intended to do to Aragorn, what he attempted to do to his son Faramir, and what was done to him.

Its a complete, 8-letter, anagram for an English word, all letters retained.

Denethor = Dethrone

There are two, and only two words that it maps to.  Dethrone and threnode.  Threnode is a song of lamentation, often for funeral. Dethrone is to remove from a place of power and prominence.

**More explorations:**

Frodo maps exclusively to Fordo, which means "to do away with or destroy", and "to overcome fatigue". Frodo is defined as the ringbearer who brought the ring to Mordor to destroy it. These are consistent with the character arc.

Similarly Samwise maps to one and only one English word: Swamies. Which is the plural of swamy, a Hindu religious teacher. This is a neutral case, because the intent is not clear.

Meriadoc maps to coadmire and racemoid which are "admire together" and "pertaining to a raceme" (which is something in botany) respectively.  This potentially counts as another neutral example.

Aragorn maps to "angora", "garron", and "organa" which are respectively a silky hair, a small sturdy workhorse, and either a system of rules for scientific study or the doubling of a melody at an interval or second part.  The fun (but stretchy) part here is the hair of Tinuviel was angora that drew Beren, and there is parallel between Aragorn and Arwen in that, and it was the song he sang at weathertop.

Elrond only maps to rondel, which is medieval form of verse in 11-14 lines with two rhymes. It might have been more French than English.  It is arguably a counter-example.

Arwen maps only to Rewan, which means re-win, or "to win again".  She won Frodo back from the wraiths. She won her way to Aragorn from her path to the ships, and she gave him the key to the second critical victory against the darkness that at the siege of Gondor.  The line of Aragorn and Arwen wins another age of life for mankind.

Isildur maps to silurid, which is a family of catfishes.  I know he died with catfishes in the Anduin after being shot with an orc arrow.

Gondolin maps only to "noodling" which at the time meant improvising on a musical instrument. Another counter-example.

Gondor maps to drongo, which is a simpleton.
Thengel maps to gentle or length.
Theodred maps to dehorted, which is the past tense of trying to dissuade, or a synonym to dissuaded.

Isengard maps to deraigns, gradines, and readings which are to dispute a claim, a series of steps raised one above another, and material that is read on an instrument (palantir)?

Angmar maps only to ragman.

Smaug maps to gaums, magus, and sagum which mean to smudge with gunk, a magician, and a cloak worn by roman soldiers.

Anduin maps only to induna, a tribal overseer in African Bantu societies.

Ingwe maps to Gwine which is the verb "to move along".

**thoughts:**
I would like to have a sense of whether this is intentional or clever accident, and if it occurs multiple times, especially in multiple books, that would suggestion intentional.

What other names of characters in LotR or Silmarilion work like this, where anagrammatical words define their broad character arc and integration into the plot?

One of my challenges here is that Tolkien was a language professor at University of Leeds, at Pembroke College, and was the Merton professor of English Language and Literature.  He translated Beowulf, and knew language like very few.  The words may be isomorphic in languages other than American English.  If there is a mapping there I wouldn't be able to recognize it.

If there is a clustering of languages for which the isomorphisms are valid, then maybe it indicates the nation on earth that he saw as being similar to the nation in Arda.

Is there any evidence that this was intentional (or at least other examples that make it clear that this is what Tolkien intended) that can be shown?

UPDATE:
I saw this online.

And this:
[image]

EdiTH TolkIEN -> __ th ien
It suggests a variant anagram.

To think about: Tinúviel

Comment: Anagram words aren't super rare.  "So about 14% of words are an anagram of at least one other word." https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2019/11/13/anagram-frequency/

Comment: @Valorum Sam spelled backwards is "mas" if you add an extra "s" it accurately describe the size of his... guts

Comment: "The One Ring" maps to "ET gin heron", so clearly the entire saga is a cryptoparody about drunken alien waterfowl.

Comment: Consider the update.

Comment: Don't stop there, there are [746 named characters](https://www.behindthename.com/namesakes/list/tolkien/name) in the three main works. Worth noting that he was a professor of Anglo Saxon and polyglot, including 4 constructed languages - before he became a writer even.

Comment: Note that the name may predate LotR; in-universe, it was the name of the leader of the Green Elves when they entered Beleriand, some 6000 years before LotR. Out-of-universe, it's not clear which character the name was applied to first. (The Elven leader may have existed under a different name before Tolkien settled on "Denethor"; whether this happened before or after LotR was written is hard to establish, at least without a more thorough reading of several volumes of HoME than I've done.)

Comment: @lucasbachmann - how many names are anagrams of a few English word but those words make a strong descriptor of the character arc or purpose?  Many of these are 7 or 8 character anagrams.

Comment: @This is still a terrible question, but with some extra examples it's no longer close-worthy.

Comment: I've edited to remove all the non-anagram names (e.g. near misses or words that just have meanings in English) since those seem irrelevant to the question being asked

Comment: I'd say the most that is in a name would be from etymology not anagrams.  Morgoth and Voldemort both have the Latin Mor = death in common because it's been scary sounding since the dawn of our languages.  I trust that's what's deliberate by Tolkien when inventing names.

Comment: Smaug for example non-anagram theory https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Smaug  "from the same Old English and Germanic roots as smial and Smeagol, the name Smaug is "the past tense of the primitive Germanic verb Smugan, to squeeze through a hole". It has been suggested that Tolkien likely thought of Old English smeag, a word used to describe a "worm""

Comment: @lucasbachmann - I would not be surprised if they lean on [Dunstan Baby sounds](https://tinyurl.com/23x77x4c) for universal and very primal human meaning.  I remember as a ~6 month old that adult sounds had many more articulations than they sound to my adult ears, and I think it came from supersaturation, small noises of mouth opening counting as an independent syllable.  "Daddy" sounded like guahurgadeen.  That might be a good way to make scary names that speak across cultures and languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably not. It's always hard to prove that something doesn't exist (just ask [Andrew Wiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)), but Tolkien's work has been read and studied in detail since its publication and many of his notes and early drafts have been published. As far as I am aware, nobody has noticed any cases where

> anagrammatical words define their [characters'] broad character arc and integration
> into the plot

(Nor has anyone noticed any other substantive tricks based on anagrams, as far as I know.) This includes Tolkien's son Christopher, who compiled the History of Middle Earth series. There is also the fact that you have tried quite hard to find such cases, and failed to do so. Most of your examples are extremely weak and tenuous (e.g. Ingwe -> gwine --- so what?). The only case I can see that comes close is Denethor -> dethrone, but even that is flawed. You write that this

> is what he intended to do to Aragorn, what he attempted to do to his
> son Faramir, and what was done to him

but Denethor didn't sit on the throne, nor would Faramir ever have done so. Had he lived, Denethor may have acted to prevent Aragorn taking the throne (he suggests as much in The Pyre of Denethor), but that's not dethroning him; you can't dethrone someone who doesn't have a throne.

Finally, note that your Arwen example is completely wrong. She played no role in rescuing Frodo from the wraiths; this is a film invention by writers who did not create her name.